# scroll bar ThumbTrack length Issue when resizing window Based on Horizontal fit for Image

Tags: c++, windows

```
    int ActualImageWidth = 1000;  
    int ActualImageHeight = 1200;  
    int WindowWidth = 800;  
    int WindowHeight = 500;  
    float resizedPercent;
```

In order to do the horizontal best fit I want to reduce or increase the actual image width to window width without changing the actual image aspect ratio. And also I should maintain the scroll bar thumb track length according to new resized image(Window Resized). For that I have done the below calculation

```
 switch(FitType)  
     {  
      case FITHORIZONTAL:  
          //find out whether resize percentage is decrease or increase  
          if(ActualImageWidth > WindowWidth) //resize decreasing  
          {  
              //find out the pecentage of decreased value  
              resizedPercent = WindowWidth/ActualImageWidth;  
          } else //resize increasing  
          {  
              //find out the pecentage of increased value  
              resizedPercent = ActualImageWidth/WindowWidth;  
          }  
          ResizedWidth = iWndwidth;  
          ResizedHeight = ActualImageHeight * resizedPercent;  
          break;  
     }
```

In order to set the scroll bar, on wm_size event I am using the below code

```
LRESULT CALLBACK my_wnd_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  
      {  
          static SCROLLINFO si;  
          static RECT rect;  
          int WndWidth = 0;  
          int WndHeight = 0;  
          case WM_CREATE :  
              {  
                  //getting image data from here.  
                  return 0;  
              }  
          case WM_SIZE :  
              {  
                  GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);  
                  WndWidth = rect.right - rect.left;  
                  WndHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;  
                  GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si);  
                  int yMaxScroll = max((int)ResizedHeight - WndHeight, 0);  
                  int yCurrentScroll = min(si.nPos, yMaxScroll);  
                  si.cbSize = sizeof(si);  
                  si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS;  
                  si.nMin  = 0;  
                  si.nMax  = ResizedHeight;  
                  si.nPage = WndHeight;  
                  si.nPos  = 0;  
                  SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);  
                  InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect, true);  
                  return 0;  
              }  
          case WM_PAINT :  
              {  
                  //try to draw image here..  
                  return 0;  
              }          
      }
```

My problem is I could not get the exact scroll bar thumb track so that I could not scroll the image until end of the image. Please do suggest the correct logic with sample

Comment: Please someone suggest me some logic to proceed

Comment: The thumb size is set by nPage.  Beware that you have to compensate for the thumb size when you get the position back since it has two sides.

Comment: when i view image in horizontal fit and resize the window and i scroll the image..i could not scroll till the end of image..what is the problem occur here..I do not know how to proceed.Please someone suggest me how to proceed.Whether it occurs in resizing or in scroll bars.

Comment: @user3034661 What do you mean horizontal fit? Do you have two scrollbars, one vertical and one horizontal? If that is the case, I don't see you performing the same calculations for the horizontal scrolling that you did for vertical. If that is not the case, I think you need to explain your problem better.

Comment: For Example: if my image width and height is 1600x2000 and client window width and height is 900x600.. now I want to fit the image horizontally. For that I will bring down the image width(1600) to window width(900) and also to maintain the original aspect ratio of the image i will also bring down the height of the image(2000) to 1125. for that I have used the above logic in FITHORIZONTAL

Then I will use above wm_size code to set the scroll bar position and thumb length. Unfortunately the full image is not shown even though the thumb tracker has reached the end of the scroll bar.

Comment: please some one help me to find the logic and proceed.I mentioned my problem clearly in the above comment.It would be great anyone can give some solution.

Comment: @user3034661 It seems to me that you calculated your max scorll but did not set it to si max. Try: `si.nMax  = yMaxScroll`

Comment: yes i tried but could not scroll the image till the end.

Comment: For Example: if my image width and height is 1600x2000 and client window width and height is 900x600.. now I want to fit the image horizontally. For that I will bring down the image width(1600) to window width(900) and also to maintain the original aspect ratio of the image i will also bring down the height of the image(2000) to 1125. for that I have used the above logic in FITHORIZONTAL Then I will use above wm_size code to set the scroll bar position and thumb length. Unfortunately the full image can not be dragged even though the thumb tracker has reached the end of the scroll bar.

Comment: I also want to know whether the calculation occured in yMaxScroll,nPage,nMax,nPos is correct

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you start your comment with @o_weisman I will get notified of comments addressed to me. In my code I also override OnVScroll like so and it works for me (you'll need to adapt it to handle your window's scroll message:

```
void CMagDialog::OnVScroll( UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar )
{
int nDelta;
int nMaxPos = yMaxScroll;

if(pScrollBar == NULL)  
{
    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        if (m_vScrollPos >= nMaxPos)
            return;
        nDelta = min(nMaxPos/100,nMaxPos-m_vScrollPos);
        break;

    case SB_LINEUP:
        if (m_vScrollPos <= 0)
            return;
        nDelta = -min(nMaxPos/100,m_vScrollPos);
        break;

    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
        if (m_vScrollPos >= nMaxPos)
            return;
        nDelta = min(nMaxPos/5,nMaxPos-m_vScrollPos);
        break;

    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
        nDelta = (int)nPos - m_vScrollPos;
        break;

    case SB_PAGEUP:
        if (m_vScrollPos <= 0)
            return;
        nDelta = -min(nMaxPos/5, m_vScrollPos);
        break;

    default:
        return;
    }
    m_vScrollPos += nDelta;
    SetScrollPos(SB_VERT,m_vScrollPos,TRUE);
    ScrollWindow(0,-nDelta);
}
```

}